# Scrape an dynamically row table using Python, Selenium and XPath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to scrape using Selenium and XPath in Python, to get the "SIRET" row from the table.
I have tried different types of XPaths, but I couldn't do it.
One problem is that the " class="reportRow" " element is changing dynamically and it can't be scrapped after the position number.
The "SIRET" raw and his "td class" subelements values, can be scrapped after the "SIRET" text or in some other way?

This are the manual steps that I am doing when I acces the site:

The site contain only the root domain.
After I acces the site thru login data, I enter an search criteria, which open an page where I have to click on an link which open an popup window whith an table.
The table contain 4 rows and 8 columns, the first row contains the name of the colums, and the other 3 rows contain data as the the "SIRET" one.
The position of that 3 rows is changing regularly, depending on the data that is recievd from an specific server.
That is why I want to scarpe that row and his values by the "SIRET" text.

My final scraped data should look like this:   SIRET  646  90  0.2%  $2.94  1.03  0.07  4.52.

Thank you very much for your inputs.

```
<div class="table_container">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="reportHead">.....</tr></tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="reportRow  ">....</tr> 
        <tr class="reportRow  ">....</tr>
        <tr class="reportRow  ">
            <td data-actual="SIRET" class="reportKeyword">SIRET</td>
            <td class="td2">646</td>
            <td class="td1">90</td>
            <td class="rcr">0.2%</td>
            <td class="td1">$2.94</td>
            <td class="td1">1.03</td>
            <td class="td1">0.07</td>
            <td class="td1 rctl">4.52</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot style="display: none;">....</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: i mean you need python code for that output

Comment: Can you share your code trials?

Comment: class="reportKeyword" this should be fixed i guess

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I can't share the entire cod because the code contains login data. I have updated the question to be more clear what I want to obtain. Thank you very much for your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use xpath like this

```
SIRET= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@data-actual='SIRET']")
```

Then you can use `.text` operation to get text

if data is dyanmically change then you have to use

```
SIRET= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='reportKeyword']")
```

Comment: Hello iamsankalp89, Thanks for your response. I have tried your Xpath. The first returns the "SIRET" text,  and the second returns the other row "data-actual" text. What I nedd is the row "SIRET" whith his values. Please read the updated questions. Thank you very much for your time and apologise for the late updated. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly, you are trying to get the string `"SIRET"` from the `<td>` node which changes dynamically. To do that you can use the following line of code :

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='reportKeyword']").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Comment: Hi, DebanjanB, thanks for your response . Your Xpath it return the first "tr class" and without the "td class" values . I nee the one with the "Siret" text.... Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: Hi, DebanjanB, I have tried the new Xpath and I recive the first row not the one that I need.

Comment: The `SIRET` text is at `<td data-actual="SIRET" class="reportKeyword">SIRET</td>` which you are able to retrieve now. Are you looking at something else? Can you update the Question with your exact Manual Steps?

Comment: Hello DebanjanB, thanks for your inputs. I have updated the questions with the manual steps. I want to scrape the entire row, the "td data" and the
"td classes" values, not only the "SIRET" text. My final scraped data should look like this:   SIRET  646  90  0.2%  $2.94  1.03  0.07  4.52.   Is ok now?

Answer (score 0):

Strange. As a matter of fact, the solution is not as intricate:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@data-actual='SIRET']/../td")
```